# Statement true regarding preimage and its properties in subsets

Tags: functions

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $A, B$ are non-void subsets of $Y$, then (where the symbols have their usual interpretation)
(a) $$f^{-1}(A)-f^{-1}(B) \supset f^{-1}(A-B)$$ but the opposite does not hold.
(b) $$f^{-1}(A)-f^{-1}(B) \subset f^{-1}(A-B)$$ but the opposite does not hold.
(C) $$f^{-1}(A-B)=f^{-1}(A)-f^{-1}(B)$$
(d) $$f^{-1}(A \cup B)=f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$$.

> My way was that $f^{-1}(x)$ only makes sense when function is bijective as its the inverse function property , so here suppose two subsets of Y A,B  if inverse exists then surely $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ will correspond to different elements in X unless $A = B$ in both cardinality and elemnets way , A-B will correspond to set in which only A elements unique are three corresponding to B , but they will still be in the elements of A , so thats why $f^{-1}(A-B)$ = $f^{-1}(A) -f^{-1}(B)$ i dont have proper proof but from this all i think this works but surely i would like to see a formal proof of this . I think answer should be C and D but i just took a example

Comment: First, the notation $f^{-1}(A)$, *when $A$ is a set*, indicates what is known as the *preimage* of $A$ under $f$—that is, the set $\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\}$. This is distinct from computing an inverse function $f^{-1}$ and applying it to everything in $A$, as there is no requirement of injectivity or surjectivity.

Second, what does $f^{-1}(A,B)$ mean? Do you mean $f^{-1}(A\cup B)$?

Comment: Yeah sir indeed A U B.